# when to use this or context with Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-context

I am trying to create an alert dialog but in the bracket in the declaration, 
on the line where it says :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

the (this) causes errors. I tried changing it to context, still more errors. HELP?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

public class userPreferences extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.userpreferences);
    EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Button save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


  save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                  alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
                  alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to save?");
                  alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                      }
                  });
                  alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", null);
                  alertDialog.show();


      }
  });

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`alertDialog` should be declared as `final` **outside** `OnClickListener`:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to save?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ...
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", null);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a reference to the currently running instance. You could use `this` to pass your Activity (which inherits from `Context`, thus why we can pass an `Activity` reference to a `Context` parameter) to the `AlertDialog.Builder`, if it's outside of the listener.

When you define an anonymous inner class, like:

> `new View.OnClickListener() {
>           ...
>       }`

The `this` reference changes to the instance of `OnClickListener`.

`AlertDialog.Builder()` expects a `Context` though! Since it's an anonymous inner class we can simply use `userPreferences.this` (because `userPreferences` is still in scope) to get the correct reference.

Comment: `AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(userPreferences.this).create();` gives an error?

Comment: it changed the error from that one word to the whole line, says i need alert dialog builder but it only seems to find alert dialog

Comment: someone helped me out! i had to declare it as final and it removed all errors. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This inside of the click listener is going to reference the click listener

```
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
                  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(userPrefereces.this).create();
                  alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
                  alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to save?");
                  alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                      }
                  });
                  alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", null);
                  alertDialog.show();


      }
  });
```

but you can get the context of the activity by

```
userPreferences.this
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the builder outside onClick method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.userpreferences);
  EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
  Button save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

  final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

  save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to save?");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", null);
                alertDialog.show();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: @droidnoob can you post the logcat?

Comment: someone helped me out! i had to declare it as final and it removed all errors. thank you!